# Apache/2.4.6 - block a large ip range with Require not ip

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm using Require not ip in .htaccess for some time now and it works well for me. I need to block a large range of IPs such as 18.128.0.0-18.255.255.255.

Should i do it line by line

Require not ip 18.128
Require not ip 18.129
Require not ip 18.130
.
.
Require not ip 18.255

or is it possible to do it all in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Require ip` accepts CIDR "prefix length" notation (address/plen, where plen is the number of '1' bits in the netmask). The range you show is written as **18.128.0.0/9**.

This is also usually the preferred notation even for networks which exactly fit octet bounaries: that is, instead of `Require ip 192.168` you should write `Require ip 192.168.0.0/16` (similarly /8, /24).

---

If you have Python installed, you can use a script to convert start & end addresses into a prefix mask (or a list of masks):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ipaddress, sys

a = ipaddress.ip_address(sys.argv[1])
b = ipaddress.ip_address(sys.argv[2])
n = ipaddress.summarize_address_range(a, b)
for net in n:
    print(net)
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast.
Added it and will monitor to make sure it does the job.

Thanks!

Comment: I found this site that does the job : 
https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr

Thanks again for the great help